# ELException on Tomcat 5.5 and JSTL 1.2

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jstl, el

### Setup:

- Apache Tomcat 5.5
- Servlet/JSP: 2.4/2.0 according to http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html
- JSTL in .WAR: 1.2

But I still get a 
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELException`

From what I have understood by reading question here at SO is that the ELException class has been moved and the container should include it. Previously in JSTL 1.1 it was provided in the JSTL .jar. Since the container is JSP 2.0 I am confused about this.

Comment: so, have to tried upgrading the container (Tomcat) ?

Comment: no this is currently a restriction in my setup unfortunately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From what I have understood by reading question here at SO is that the
>   ELException class has been moved and the container should include it.
>   Previously in JSTL 1.1 it was provided in the JSTL .jar. Since the
>   container is JSP 2.0 I am confused about this.

You need to do either of following

Upgrade the Tomcat container to latest

or

downgrade the JSTL library to 1.0/1.1 which can be available here from Apache Tag lib implementation : http://tomcat.apache.org/taglibs/standard/

Edit: excerpt from Apache library download for Compatibility to JSTL version to Tomcat Version

[image]

as you can see , you are using the JSP 2.0 and JSTL 1.2 which in-compatible. Hence some classes might be upgraded or downgraded

Comment: I downgraded JSTL to 1.1.2