# EL tag c:forEach only iterates once

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

From the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010123/elexception-on-tomcat-5-5-and-jstl-1-2/16010545?noredirect=1#16010545), my setup is the following:

### Setup:

- Apache Tomcat 5.5
- Servlet/JSP: 2.4/2.0 according to http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html
- JSTL in .WAR: <strike>1.2</strike> changed to 1.1.2 now.

In my web.xml I have like so:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">
```

And in my .JSP

```
<%  Set<ProductInfo> productInfoSet = (Set<ProductInfo>)session.getAttribute("productInfoSet");%>

<c:forEach items="${productInfoSet}" var="productInfo">
    <c:out value="aa"/>
</c:forEach>
```

In debug I can see that the `Set` contains three elements, but the string `aa` is only printed once. How come?

NOTE! the scriptlet tag is only for debug purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

productInfoSet != productInfoSet

Try to use

```
<c:forEach items="${sessionScope.productInfoSet}" var="productInfo">
```

Comment: Thanks! But I don't understand why the variable in the scriptlet cannot be used?

Comment: You have the variable in multiple scopes, your ${productInfoSet} was request-scope.